Old film about a guy who get out of prison to kills the people that blamed him for robbery
The movie is an older film, either from the 1990s or early 2000s. It's about a guy that's a part of a bank robbery. He takes the fall and goes to prison, then when he gets out he hunts down and kills the people that blamed him and killed his wife/girlfriend.
Most of what I remember of the movie is that he's basically living in the same motel room where they killed his wife/girlfriend. And at the end of the movie, they have him tied up in a chair and he breaks his wrist so the bone is sticking out and stabs the guy that has him tied up in the neck.
It was in English, USA and it was a low budget movie. There wasn't any big name in the movie.

"older film"? Please be more specific. Also, please provide information about the language, industry etc.

Spontaneous i can think of at least 10 movies which match this description, that is a common trope.we need more details

It was either in the 1990s or early 2000s. Most of what I remember of the movie is that he's basically living in the same motel room that they killed his wife/girlfriend. And at the end of the movie they have him tied up in a chair and he breaks his wrist so the bone is sticking out and stabs the guy that has him tied up in the neck

Was it in English? USA? Was it big budget or low budget?

It almost sounded like "Payback" with Mel Gibson (1999). But the whole "stabbing in the neck with the broken arm-bone" part is missing.

It was English USA and it was a low budget movies. There wasn't any big names in the movie

Thanks, added. Hopefully it'll reopen, and then you'll get your answer. :)

Posted a match. Thanks for supplying more details; I just wish the title was 'Movie about a guy stabbing someone with his own broken wrist bone'. It might be too grisly for this site, but it's somewhat cooler. ;)

You're looking for Bullets, Blood & A Fistful of Ca$h from 2006. From the trailer:

A hardboiled action thriller written and directed by Sam Akina, starring Thom Doty as Ca$h - the toughest, meanest, dirtiest, most rotten sonofabitch you ever met. Double-crossed in a bank robbery and left for dead, Ca$h returns to the city after ten years in prison - seeking revenge for the murder of his wife by ex-partner Hector Gonzales (Jerry Lloyd). With armies of colorful crooks at his disposal, and various criminal stories unfolding in the backdrop, Ca$h has his work cut out for him. Luckily, he's only ever been good at two things....and killing people is one of them.

It ends in the exact manner you've described, with Ca$h tied to a chair with all of his limbs broken, then using his broken wrist bone to stab the villain in the neck. Here's the trailer:




Not an answer just freaking ecstatic OMG, I've been looking for this exact movie for 11 years, asked once on some other site and no one could help, this has literally made my day.
